# Why is it possible to call a higher order function's extension function parameter as a normal function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, compilation, extension-methods, higher-order-functions

Let's consider this code:

```
class Receiver

fun higherOrder(extensionBlock: Receiver.() -> Unit) {
    Receiver().extensionBlock() // works
    extensionBlock(Receiver()) // works
}

fun Receiver.extension() = Unit
fun f() {
    Receiver().extension() // works
    extension(Receiver()) // unresolved reference
}
```

In my mind extension's functional signature is `Receiver.() -> Unit`, same as `extensionBlock` parameter's; i.e. we can call `higherOrder(Receiver::extension)` fine. If this is true, I don't understand why the normal function call syntax is not consistent between an extension function and a parameter of the same type. I'm actually happy that `extension(Receiver())` is not allowed, so there's only one way to call extension functions. So I guess the main question is ***Why* can I do `extensionBlock(Receiver())` when `extensionBlock` has an extension function signature?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe looking at the byte code helps...

`extensionBlock : Receiver.() -> Unit` is a `Function1<Receiver, Unit>`. Under the hood both calls are basically similar to `extensionBlock.invoke(Receiver())`... (you could have even written that one as well in your comparison...) ... so the compiler does the magic that both work... why isn't it doing that also in the extension variant?

Extension functions are just static functions that take the receiver as argument. Now a guess why it isn't supported the same way as with higher order functions, even though technically it could be possible.
Having something as follows in place, should it be an extension function then too?

```
fun extension(r : Receiver) = Unit // to extend or not to...?
```

I think it should, if you want to support `extension(Receiver())` for extension functions (and from the byte code there is no difference). For now you couldn't have both functions in place, as you would get a platform declaration clash then (which basically speaks in favor to why `extension(Receiver())` should work with the extension function).

I wonder whether it would be more or less logic for the compiler to handle if it were this way... to be honest, I like that higher order functions and extension functions differ in that regard... For me an extension function or a function taking something as argument are two different sort of things... it would probably be more confusing if an extension function could be used in both ways, i.e. `extension(Receiver())` and `Receiver().extension()`... probably it would be more confusing if ~normal functions would also be available as extension functions...

A pity, but also logical, that this on the Java side works: `<WrapperClass>.extension(new Receiver())` (but we have no real extension there, so it's ok ;-))

Answer (score 3):

These examples are two different things: First one is a function **type** with receiver `A.() -> B`, second one is an extension function.

### 1. Fuction with receiver:

**TL;DR**: `A.() -> B` is different way to write `(A) -> B`. It does not extend anything.

> Non-literal values of function types with and without receiver are
>   interchangeable, so that the receiver can stand in for the first
>   parameter, and vice versa. For instance, a value of type (A, B) -> C
>   can be passed or assigned where a A.(B) -> C is expected and the other
>   way around:

```
val repeatFun: String.(Int) -> String = { times -> this.repeat(times) }
val twoParameters: (String, Int) -> String = repeatFun // OK
```

[Kontlin doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type)

In your case, the code applied to the explanation would look like:

```
val typeFunWithReceiver = Receiver.() -> Unit
val typeFunWithParam : (Receiver) -> Unit = typeFunWithReceiver // It does NOT extend Receiver
```

It is indeed confusing also to me now you're mentioning it. Even in the kotlin doc they refer to the resemblance:

> This behavior is similar to extension functions, which also allow you
>   to access the members of the receiver object inside the body of the
>   function.

[Source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver)

### 2. Extension function

**TL;DR**: `A.funName() -> B` extends the `A` class by the function `funName()`. It is not a method type like before.

> Kotlin provides the ability to extend a class with new functionality
>   without having to inherit from the class or use design patterns such
>   as Decorator.

[Source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions)